# Django form_valid error. Can anyone find the error?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-generic-views

I am trying to use the value from the URL on CreateView

My models are like that:  Categoria > Serie

I have made a URL that `path('nova-serie/<categoria>', NovaSerie.as_view(), name='nova_serie'),`

The URL to create a new Serie is like that: **/nova-serie/3**

I am trying to use `form_valid` but I am receiving this message:

***Cannot assign "'3'": "Serie.categoria" must be a "Categoria" instance.***

#### views.py

```py
class NovaSerie(CreateView):
    model = Serie
    form_class = SerieForm
    template_name = 'nova_serie.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        url = self.request.path_info
        parte_final_url = url.replace('/nova-serie/', '')
        form.instance.categoria = parte_final_url
        return super(NovaSerie).form_valid(form)
```

#### forms.py

```py
class SerieForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Serie
        fields = (
            'serie',

        )
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(),  # attrs={class="title"}
        }
```

Can anyone here give me a help?

Comment: In the url path it must include the type of data, example:

`path('patient/appointment/<int:pk>/update/', PatientAppointmentUpdateView.as_view(), name="patientappointmentupdate"),`

see in mine it shows that i and sending a int and it will be the primary key.

Comment: @bryant thanks ... But it´s not a primary key... In my case is a Foreign Key...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to do string processing on the path. You can obtain the URL parameters with `self.kwargs`. Furthermore if you want to specify the `id` of the `.categoria`, you should set `.categoria_id`:

```
class NovaSerie(CreateView):
    model = Serie
    form_class = SerieForm
    template_name = 'nova_serie.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.categoria_id = self.kwargs['categoria']
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I would furthermore advise to specify the `categoria` URL parameter as an `int`:

```
path('nova-serie/<int:categoria>', NovaSerie.as_view(), name='nova_serie'),
```

that way if the value is not an integer it will not fire the view.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this...  But with those changes Django sends me an error message: __'super' object has no attribute 'form_valid'__

Comment: @AndreNevares: yes, you used `super` the wrong way. In Python-2.x it is with `self`, but in Python-3.x, you can simply use `super()`.

Comment: Message error: __FOREIGN KEY     constraint failed__  ```class NovaSerie(CreateView):
    model = Serie
    form_class = SerieForm
    template_name = 'nova_serie.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.categoria_id = self.kwargs['categoria']
        return super().form_valid(form)```

Comment: Thanks for your time... I really appreciate it

Comment: @AndreNevares: that means there is no `Categoria` with `id=3`, so then the URL does not contain a valid thing to reference.

Comment: If you make a request to `nova-serie/3` then a `categoria` with `id=3` should of course first exist.

Comment: It was cache!   Thanks so much!!!  God bless you!!!